# When does a read() on a TCP socket return

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp

Can someone please explain, when exactly the read-function I use to get data from a TCP-socket does return?

I use the code below for reading from a measurement system. This system delivers data with a frequency of 15 Hz. `READ_TIMEOUT_MS` has a value of `200`
Furthermore `READ_BUFFER_SIZE` has a value of `40000`.
All works fine, but what happens is, `read()` returns 15 times a second with `1349` bytes read.

By reading Pitfall 5 in the following documentation I would have expected, that the buffer is filled up completely:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-sockpit/

Init:

```
sock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (socket < 0)
{
    goto fail0;
}

struct sockaddr_in server;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPAddress);
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(Port);
if (connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)))
{
    goto fail1;
}

struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = READ_TIMEOUT_MS / 1000;
tv.tv_usec = (READ_TIMEOUT_MS % 1000) * 1000;
if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv, sizeof(struct timeval)))
{
    goto fail1;
}

return true;

fail1:
    close(sock);
    sock = -1;
fail0:
    return false;
```

Read:

```
unsigned char buf[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];
int len = read(sock, buf, sizeof(buf));
if (len <= 0)
{
    return NULL;
}

CBinaryDataStream* pData = new CBinaryDataStream(len);
pData->WriteToStream(buf, len);
return pData;
```

I hope this question is not a duplicate, because I searched for an answer before I asked.
Please let me know if you need some further information.

Comment: It returns whenever your OS feels like it. You have to be prepared to get less bytes than you want. Pitfall 5 actually implies it. The diagram shows a read of 1024 bytes, but the text talks about it returning 200 bytes.

Comment: You might want to look into [`select`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) for a more easily controlled timeout.

Comment: @n.m.: I understood this behavior of the OS. But I'm wondering why the call of `read()` returns the desired no of bytes every time.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. If you ask to read N bytes, you can get anywhere from 0 to N bytes. Is there a question about the preceding sentence?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are using Linux. The [manpage for read says](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read):

> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end
>   of file), and the file position is advanced by this number. It is not
>   an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested;

TCP sockets model a byte-stream and not a block- or message-oriented protocol. Calling read on a socket returns if there are any data available in the application's buffer. In principle, the data arrives in the network card, is then transferred to the kernel space where it is processed by the kernel and the network stack. Finally, the `read` syscall gets the data from the kernel space and transfers it to user space.

When reading from a socket you have to expect an arbitrary number of bytes that can be read. A call to read returns as soon as there is anything in the read buffer or when an error occurred. You cannot predict or assume how many bytes may be available.

In addition, the call can return without reading anything because the OS has been interrupted. This happens quite often when debug or profile your application. You have to handle this in your application layer.

The complete receiver path is surprisingly complex when you want to have high data rates or low latency. The kernel and NICs implement many optimizations to e.g. spread load over cores, increase locality and offload processing to the NIC. Here are some additional links you may find interesting:

- https://www.lmax.com/blog/staff-blogs/2016/05/06/navigating-linux-kernel-network-stack-receive-path/
- https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-achieve-low-latency/
- http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/06/22/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-receiving-data
- http://syuu.dokukino.com/2013/05/linux-kernel-features-for-high-speed.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I'm working on a Linux platform. You say "A call to read returns as soon as there is anything in the read buffer." Does this mean that the bytes returned by `read()` simply "match" in my case for any reason?

Comment: @bushmills There are plenty websites describing the hole path from NIC to application, e.g. http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-tcp-ip-network-stack/.

Comment: @bushmills Yes, calling read can get an arbitrary number of bytes up to the supplied maximum. It could 1. You have to implement framing yourself in the application, e.g. by reading in a loop until you receive the expected number of bytes for a message.

Comment: I implemented the framing in order to get all the data sent by the measurement system. Since all works fine, this is not an issue. I was simply wondering, why I get the desired no of bytes every time, even this is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the website which offers comprehensive information about TCP/IP communication. I will have a closer look at it.

Comment: @bushmills I've added some more links which describe the receiver part and optimizations by the kernel and the NIC.

Comment: Thanks for the large amount of information. Especially the documentation provided by the link in the upper comment was quite interesting. Unfortunately I couldn't find the information I asked for.

Comment: @bushmills The answer is that `read` returns as soon as there is any amount of data availabile. What you are seeing is just a random effect.

Comment: ok, thank you. that is what I just got from the documentations.